# how to improve the performance of this recursion code in mathematica

Tags: performance-tuning, recursion

```
Clear[r, re, p, pmax, delta, imagesize, delta]
ClearSystemCache[]
re[0, r_] := Sqrt[8/Pi]*((1 - r)/r)^(1/4)*1; 
re[1, r_] := Sqrt[8/Pi]*((1 - r)/r)^(1/4)*-1*2*(1 - 2*r); 
re[p_, r_] := re[p, r] = Sqrt[8/Pi]*((1 - r)/r)^(1/4)*(-1)^p*(re[1, r]*re[p - 1, r] - re[p - 2, r]); 
imagesize = 32; 
pmax = 10; 
delta = 2/imagesize; 
Table[r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]; re[pmax, r], {x, -1 + delta/2, 1 - delta/2, delta}, {y, 1 - delta/2, -1 + delta/2, -delta}];
```

when the imagesize and pmax increase, the time will become unacceptable. So, I would ask if we can use compile of other methods to speed up,like: for imagesize is 256 and pmax is 120, the time will be about 10 seconds. In my code, I also use the memoization to store the value during the evaluation which I will use in the future.

Comment: You might try this Simplify[RSolve[{re[0] == c, re[1] == c*-1*2*(1 - 2*r), re[p] == c*(-1)^p*((c*-1*2*(1 - 2*r))*re[p - 1] - re[p - 2])}, re[p], p]] /. c -> Sqrt[8/Pi]*((1 - r)/r)^(1/4) There are lots of common subexpressions in that result which you could calculate once, store in a variable and the replace all those subexpressions with simple variables. If you do all that carefully and simplify the result you might end up with a reasonable sized expression with a few variables and no recursion. – @Bill

Comment: Reference for the quotations?

Comment: You have numbered equations (3), (14), etc.  What is paper or book they are from?

Comment: This is cross-posed to Wolfram Community (which should have been noted in both posts).

Comment: Yes, Thank you for noticing@DanielLichtblau

Comment: And you should have mentioned the cross-posting in Baidu Tieba.

Comment: yes, until I get the right answer. ni zhen pi----haha.@xzczd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please double-check for correctness.

```
re = Compile[{{pmax, _Integer}, {r, _Real}},
  Block[{C1, Cold, Cp, buffer},
   If[0. <= r <= 1.,
    If[pmax == 0, Cp = 1., C1 = 2. (1. - 2. r);
     Cold = 1.;
     Cp = C1;
     Do[buffer = Cp;
      Cp = C1 Cp - Cold;
      Cold = buffer, {p, 2, pmax}];
     ];
    Sqrt[8./Pi] ((1 - r)/r)^(1/4) (-1.)^pmax Cp,
    0.
    ]
   ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
  Parallelization -> True]
```

The sum expression for testing purposes:

```
R[p_, r_] := Sqrt[8./Pi] ((1 - r)/r)^(1/4) Sum[
   (-1)^k (p - k)!/k!/(p - 2 k)! (2 (2 r - 1))^(p - 2 k),
   {k, 0, Quotient[p, 2]}]
```

Usage example:

```
imagesize = 256;
delta = 2./imagesize;
x = Subdivide[-1. + delta/2, 1. - delta/2, imagesize - 1];
y = Subdivide[-1. + delta/2, 1. - delta/2, imagesize - 1];
result = re[120, Sqrt[0.5 Outer[Plus, x^2, y^2]]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.006015

Notice that the function `re` will throw errors if you try to feed it with second arguments from outside the unit interval.

Check for correctness:

```
plist = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 20];
xlist = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 20];
Max[Abs[Outer[re, plist, xlist] - Outer[R, plist, xlist]]]
```

> 1.2568*10^-9

Comment: it seems the result is not right, I checked the code:"Sqrt[8./Pi] ((1 - r)/r)^(1/4) (-1.)^pmax Cp". According to the equation (14), the p will change, not the only pmax. And thank you very much.

Comment: Hm. I don't think that this makes sense. For given $p_\mathrm{max}$, we want to compute $R_{p_\mathrm{max}}(r)$; therefore, we need $C_{p_\mathrm{max}}(r)$. And the latter is computed recursively. (Notice that I did it iteratively; this is in general faster than doing it recursively.)

Comment: @look Hmmm. I guess I found the issue. I forgot to make updates to `Cold`. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks for updating, It seems the result is different from another answer. according to my result from my own method, I think his method is right so far. But your performance is much better.

Comment: Please try this: plist = {0}
xlist = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 20];
Max[Abs[Outer[re, plist, xlist] - Outer[R, plist, xlist]]]

Comment: The case $p_{\max}=0$ is now also covered correctly. I wonder what you will need it for.

Comment: I need all the values, when 0<=p<=pmax, And I cannot understand this code:Sqrt[0.5 Outer[Plus, x^2, y^2]], what is the 0.5 for, please?

Comment: The `0.5` is for scaling the distances to the center with $1/\sqrt{2}$ in order to get feasible values ($0 \leq r \leq 1$) for the second argument of `re`; otherwise you would get non-real results (and many error messages). I doubt that you want to do that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. but I want the complex result to be 0 and in their place, How can I do that?

Comment: I think I want to use the re[] like:result = re[120, Sqrt[Outer[Plus, x^2, y^2]]]; but it said "CompiledFunction::cfne: Numerical error encountered; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.". Also I try to change the {r, _Real} to {r, _Complexl}, it said:Compile::initvar: The variable Cp has not been initialized or has been initialized to Null.Compile::cptype: Times is not supported for type Void; evaluation will use the uncompiled function.The variable buffer has not been initialized or has been initialized to Null......

Comment: You can use `If` for checking if $r$ lies between $0$ and $1$ (see my edit).

Comment: I think this is what I want. Thanks.